# Creating dynamic queries depending on parameter passed in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is it possible to create something cleaner out of this dynamic query:

```
@photos = Photo.within(100, :origin => [params[:latitude], params[:longitude]]) unless (params[:latitude].nil? || params[:longitude].nil?)

if @photos.nil? then
  conditions  = String.new
  values      = Array.new

  params.each_key do |key|

    if key == 'since_id' then
      conditions << " AND " unless conditions.length == 0
      conditions << "id > ?"
      values << params[key]
    elsif key == 'user_id' then
      conditions << " AND " unless conditions.length == 0
      conditions << "user_id = ?"
      values << params[key]
    elsif key == 'id' then
      conditions << " AND " unless conditions.length == 0
      conditions << "id = ?"
      values << params[key]
    end
  end

  values.insert(0, conditions)
  @photos = Photo.limit(15).order("created_at DESC").where(values) unless values.nil?

end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the right way to do it is use scopes

```
scope :older_than, lambda { |value| where('id > (?)', value) if value }
scope :with_id, lambda { |value| where('id = (?)', value) if value }
scope :for_user, lambda { |value| where('user_id = (?)', value) if value }
```

later in search

```
@photos = Photo.within(100, :origin => [params[:latitude], params[:longitude]]) 
          unless (params[:latitude].nil? || params[:longitude].nil?)

@photos = Photo.with_id( params[ :id ] )
               .older_than( params[ :since_id ] )
               .for_user( params[ :user_id ] )
               .order("created_at DESC")
               .limit(15)
```

Comment: Yes it is. Since it wouldn't make sense to have a id as params and a since_id (they should be mutually exclusive)

Comment: The query I generate is OK. What I want to do is make it prettier. I think it's cumbersome the way I layed it out. I am looking for alternatives that would make it more maintainable

Comment: if I got everything right only `id` or `since_id` is present. What is  `Photo.within` for?

Comment: Hmm the scoping is a good idea. as for the the within, this is a geokit gem to allow geolocation. it's only used when the client asks to restrict the result to a given area

Comment: I really appreciate that you spent some times editing your answer as you were getting more info. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me re-write a piece of functionality inside of an API I am developing. Thanks for the tips!