# Rails 3 joining multiple where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Would like to build rails active record query with multiple optional where conditions.

Example:

I have a patient search form that able to search by id, name and email address. The pseudo code would be as below:

```
where_sql = ""
where_sql = {'name = ?", params[:name]} if params[:name]
where_sql = {'id = ?", params[:id]} if params[:id]
where_sql = {'email = ?", params[:email]} if params[:email]

Patient.where(where_sql)
```

How do I build following queries without worrying about sql injection.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419472/creating-dynamic-queries-depending-on-parameter-passed-in-rails-3/6421870#6421870 for clues

Answer (score 1):

If you use questionmark "?" placeholders or hashes ActiveRecord automatically escapes the values for you. See injection countermeasures in rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

This might be a nice use case for the ransack gem (MetaWhere rewrite) https://github.com/ernie/ransack

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only equal conditions, you can do it like:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:name] = params[:name] if params[:name]
conditions[:id] = params[:id] if params[:id]
conditions[:email] = params[:email] if params[:email]
Patient.where(conditions)
```

Also, take a look to a great searchlogic gem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I am not using it for equal conditions only.