# Rails 3: Looping through parameters for dynamic based MySQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, optional-parameters

I have developed a small API that returns some minor JSON objects (mainly small resources, nothing fancy), but I am in a situation where I need to expand one of the API endpoints to return a little more than just whats there currently.

For Example - Currently, I have the following in my routes:

```
resources :school_types do
        resources :schools
      end
```

So, if a user accesses `/api/v1/school_types/1/schools.json` an entire listing of schools will come back based on the `school_type_id`

Well, I am now wanting to take it a little further and do the following:
`/api/v1/school_types/1/schools.json?param_1=foo&param_2=bar`

So when I construct the `ActiveRecord` call it would dynamically generate the SQL query based on the parameters passed in.

This is what I have so far:

```
conditions = ""
      params.except(:controller, :format, :action).each_with_index do |value, index|
        conditions << "#{params[index]} = #{value} AND "
      end
```

This is the conditions variable output: `" = [\"state_id\", \"1\"] AND  = [\"district_id\", \"1\"] AND  = [\"school_type_id\", \"1\"] AND "`

Obviously I am doing something wrong, LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using a tool like [MetaSearch](http://erniemiller.org/projects/metasearch/) rather than rolling your own. Your current implementation is highly subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am going to take a look into the gem you suggested. Would something like this work too? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6421870/282343

Comment: Yes. Depending on how many different parameters you need to support, it may be simpler to use custom scopes than to implement MetaSearch. The important thing is to use Rails methods to assemble the query rather than simply concatenating and interpolating strings.